# Creating a loop over existing function that changes the one parameter the function takes into many paramaters

Tags: python

So this is what I wish to do. I have a function and some paramaters:

```
Names = ["Whaaaaa", "whoooo", "mamo", "tete", "tetsae"]
QC_ID = 100
NAME_FMT = "DEVICE_%s_%s"

def createE(Names, size = None):
    eName = NAME_FMT % ((",").join(Names[0]), "*")
    return eName
```

What I want to do is, without changing the function, make it print out the text of extent name over and over depending on the number I input. So for example it would be something like this:

```
createE(Names[0:3])
DEVICE_100_Whaaaaa
DEVICE_100_whoooo
DEVICE_100_mamo
```

What the function does now is this:

```
createE(Names[0:3])
DEVICE_100_Whaaaaa, DEVICE_100_whoooo, DEVICE_100_mamo
```

And finally I want to take the output (because `DEVICE_100_Whaaaaa` would create some output) and add it to a list:

```
e = []
e.append(createE(Names[0:3]))
print e
["Hello", "I", "Am"]
```

The problem I'm having with is this `createE(Names[0:3])` I need it to print in every line and it does not do it. :( I can't change the function itself.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The [map](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) function takes a function and an iterable (like a list), and returns a list of results of the function applied to each element of the input.